# Obj C to Swift Conversion - Closures

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How would I call this using Swift? Can't seem to get the right syntax!

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^testBlock)(UIImage *image);
```

So far I've got:

```
imag.testBlock({(image:UIImage)->Void in
    println("test")
})
```

But it's giving me an error:

(UIImage) -> Void is not convertible to UIImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `testBlock` is an Objective-C property bound to a function.  So, in your problem code, are you assigning `testBlock` or are you calling the function bound to `testBlock`?

```
imag.testBlock = { (image:UIImage) -> Void in
  println ("test")
}
```

then to use:

```
imag.testBlock (/* call with some image */)
```

Comment: The image in the function has already been assigned, like so:

 `self.cropBlock(self.sampleImage); `, and now I want to access that image. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When defining a closure: 
Closures are typically enclosed in curly braces { } and are defined by a function type () -> (), where -> separates the arguments and the return type, followed by the in keyword which separates the closure header from its body.

```
{ (params) -> returnType in
  statements
}
```

See: http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/

So in your case you shouldn't use Void as returnType, when you want to return an UIImage

```
imag.testBlock( { (image: UIImage) -> UIImage in
     return UIImage(....) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still getting an error it seems, '(UIImage) -> UIImage' is not convertible to 'UIImage', with the following syntax:

    `imag.testBlock( { (image: UIImage) -> UIImage in
            println(image)
            return UIImage()
        })`

Answer (score 0):

Your Objective-C property is a block that takes an `UIImage` parameter. When you do

```
imag.testBlock({(image:UIImage)->Void in
    println("test")
})
```

You are calling the block and passing in another block, which doesn't make sense for your situation.

All you need is `imag.testBlock(UIImage(named: "some_image"))`